# How to get url structure i'd like in LocomotiveCMS?

Tags: locomotivecms

I'm very new to LocomotiveCMS. I'm trying to do a CMS for an artist agency. The agency represents several artists and each artist will have some pages: bio, agenda, news, gallery, etc. I'd like to have an urls like:

```
www.example.com/artists/artist_name/bio
www.example.com/artists/artist_name/news
...
```

I guess I have to create an Artist content type and maybe a new content type for each artist page type and use a reference to the artist in each ones. But I don't know how to get the urls i want.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this right now using the master branch. There is a wildcard branch (https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/tree/wildcards) that should allow you to do what you want but I have not used it.